# How to use Realsense in python function save_single_frameset

Tags: python, realsense

I'm using the python wrapper of Realsense with the D435 camera

trying to apply the save_single_frameset to my project

I run with Python 2.7 and the latest realsense library

I use the code as here

```
saver = rs.save_single_frameset()
frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
saver.process(frames)
```

it is defined as filter and it saves every record as a separate bag, but there is a problem

the frameset doesn't have any depth data,

they can be seen in the realsense viewer, but in the viewer it shows alway 0 meter of distance

I also asked on github but it was closed without explaination
https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/4020

my data here
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gwyfJPE9nwYzyF-xGc4gqyrfuHttErim

one version using the code rs.recorder

[with recorder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W11Rb.jpg)

and the save single framset version

[save single frameset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCiK3.jpg)

as here is seems similar, only while getting depth data is the problem

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? Thank you!

Comment: unfortunately, I still can't find the method to get depth from frameset

Comment: Compiling the branch ``https://github.com/lramati/librealsense/archive/ssfs.zip`` did the trick. There was a bug in the save_single_frameset() method for which a fix was committed. Check out ``https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/4801`` for further reference.

Comment: thanks @bernland I saw your issue also. I tried with the latest pyrealsense binding(2.28.0.1093) from pip install, it is still the same. Now i still use the rs.recorder, and sleep for 0.2 seconds, sometimes one frame, sometimes 2.